# Ruby on Rails maintenance and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How are your experiences with RoR maintenance and RSpec.

- Is RSpec good for real use, I mean do developers generally use it, or is it something you can live without?
- How is with maintenance aspects of RoR, web hosting - is it cheap and abundant like say PHP hosting, gem dependencies and updates, changing the database model, etc.?

I'm researching couple of technologies for the next web project and RoR seems ok at a first glance, but wouldn't like to jump into something that requires a lot to maintain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Rspec` is very popular but Rails creator thinks it's not that useful since there is Test::Unit, a built-in test library: http://www.rubyinside.com/dhh-offended-by-rspec-debate-4610.html. Personnaly, I like Rspec and use it daily.
- Hosting Rails is really easy:

  - `Heroku` is quick and free until you need solid configuration
  - On a real server, once you setup `Ruby`, `Apache` and `Passenger` (or `Nginx` or whatever), you'll just have to configure your VHosts
- Deploying is dead simple thanks to `Capistrano`
- In general, I love Rails because everything is thought to be simple to use. Basically, the dependencies built as `gems` are so easy to manage thanks to `Bundler`.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I hope Heroku, Capistrano, Passenger and Bundler are not too much of a burden and a hassle on their own.

Comment: Well, if that's the case... ;)

Comment: No Really, you'll see that almost everything that you need is already bundled as a gem and can be integrated in few lines if code. See http://railscasts.com, this is a very valuable asset to see Rails in action.

Answer (score 2):

Rspec is definitely good for real use and most Rails developers use it a lot for their testing purposes. Generally speaking, Rails and testing are tied together. You can of course live without rspec, but testing is pretty important. You can always use test/unit, shoulda or other solutions, as long as you use something.

I would advice that you get a dedicated server for Rails or host it on Heroku. These are probably the best ways to go about it. Maintaining the projects is a whole easier than php or other choices.

Generally speaking, i highly recommend Rails :)